# How to disable 'strict' mode in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

IM so sorry for this rookie question but its driving me crazy. I bought a react component pack and came with this complex webpack configuration, and actually doesn't let me compile until I resolve some strict syntax rules such as spaces, commas, singlequotes and so on.....

[image]

ANd this is my large webpack.config.dev.js file:

```
module.exports = {

  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      PnpWebpackPlugin,
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [
      PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve(
                'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
              ),

              plugins: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                  { helpers: true },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,

              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
            }),
          },
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            }),
          },
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({ importLoaders: 2 }, 'sass-loader'),
          },
          {
            test: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ),
          },
          {
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
      publicPath: publicPath,
    }),
  ],

  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  performance: false,
};
```

For starters I think the issue is with this file isn't? I want to compile my project with normal syntax and no strict babel rules (some of them kind of useless such as a comma after the last object param).

Please any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First, never **buy** something that is free (if you're buying a tutorial, then that's different, but buying code won't help you learn if you don't understand what you're looking at). There are plenty of free tools, setups, tutorials, and guides out there that cover your development needs. For example, the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is free, highly supported, and is a very novice-developer friendly boilerplate.

Anyway, what you're seeing are `ESlint` errors. [ESlint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) is a great tool to standardize your code. It forces developers to write code a specific way to integrate well across projects (prevents mixing syntax rules and styles). Therefore, I don't recommend disabling it and instead, you should fix your errors accordingly.

To address some of your errors:

[comma-dangle](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle)

[import/order](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md)

[key-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing#enforce-consistent-spacing-between-keys-and-values-in-object-literal-properties-key-spacing)

[qoutes](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes#enforce-the-consistent-use-of-either-backticks-double-or-single-quotes-quotes)

[arrow-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-spacing#require-space-beforeafter-arrow-functions-arrow-arrow-spacing)

[semi](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi#require-or-disallow-semicolons-instead-of-asi-semi)

[prefer-template](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template#suggest-using-template-literals-instead-of-string-concatenation-prefer-template)

[react/destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md)

[prefer-arrow-callback](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback)

[space-before-function-paren](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren)

[no-var](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var)

[no-unused-var](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#disallow-unused-variables-no-unused-vars)

[arrow-parens](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens#require-parens-in-arrow-function-arguments-arrow-parens)

[comma-spacing](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-spacing#enforces-spacing-around-commas-comma-spacing)

[react/jsx-first-prop-new-line](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-first-prop-new-line.md)

All of those errors are simple mistakes that can be easily fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I’ve worked lots of react projects before in teams where I was not in charge of deployment and delivery, just code, that’s why I’m not very familiar with we pack configuration. So in resume you recommend continue working in strict configuration?

Comment: Yes. It'll force you to write better code. In fact, I'd encourage you to use `prop-types` or `flow` for prop validation and to start using a testing library (like `jest`) to have even stricter policies.  Why? Because when you have a lot of moving parts, these strict policies can prevent someone from changing one line of code and breaking your entire app. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the checks then it is probably sufficient to remove the following section:

```
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  use: [
    {
      options: {
        formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

      },
      loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
    },
  ],
  include: paths.appSrc,
},
```

However, consider keeping the checks as a pre-commit or pre-push hook. It will help the health of your codebase considerably.

If there are some rules that you really do not like, there will be a `.eslintrc.js` file or similar in your project directory that you can use to customise the rules.